# Customize product page

Tags: magento2, custompage

I'm testing Magento on the localhost and **I need to make some changes to the product page template**.

I have been able to create a custom theme and modify it but I do not understand **how to override the custom product page**.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to exactly achieve, you can extend any template file by looking at the Magento Catalog Module architecture. You can find it here **/vendor/magento/module-catalog** to know what is the module identifier, you need to look at the module **'registration.php'** therefore, it is **'Magento_Catalog'** that you are looking for.

That being said, you will need to extend each template file you want to customize into your own theme. So there is how you do it.

Create this architecture:

```
/app/design/frontend/<VENDOR>/<THEME>/Magento_Catalog/
```

in which you will be able to extend layouts into

```
/app/design/frontend/<VENDOR>/<THEME>/Magento_Catalog/layout
```

and templates into

```
/app/design/frontend/<VENDOR>/<THEME>/Magento_Catalog/templates
```

Please, follow this link for a complete frontend guide on how layouts in Magento 2 works.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/bk-frontend-dev-guide.html

Comment: Ok, than you very much. I need to add an iframe to the product page, and i am not sure if it  is better to costumize the theme layout or use a product attribute to do it

Comment: Where do you need to add the iframe? Can you locate any block in which you would like to have it? Or you may wan't to create a block from scratch.

Comment: I'd like to show the iframe at the beginning of the product page, or replace the gallery with it. It has to be dynamic and change for every product